# Roomba simulation in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, roomba

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a Roomba model for gazebo (Not the full Turtlebot) ? Has anyone got it, care to refer me to those launch/world files ?

**UPDATE**

Thank you Jeff, it looks perfect !

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12538/roomba-simulation-in-gazebo/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-05**:
@JonW Yeah, I did give a thought to that - but as roomba is a popular robot, I would guess that enthusiasts have surely made a gazebo model of it.

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-01-05**:
Would removing the kinect sensor and frame from the turtlebot urdf description be sufficient?  That should leave only the iRobot create base and sensors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I maintain a URDF for the Create (which is functionally identical, unless you want to simulate the vacuum) here:
http://code.google.com/p/aptima-ros-pkg/

The package name is irobot_create_description and has launch files for gazebo in the 'launch' directory

There are still some TODO items like simulating the bumper and drop sensors, but if you just need odometry it should work fine.

UPDATE: Looking at the turtlebot_description package it looks like it was originally a fork of my URDF.  I'll see if there's any additions they made that would be useful for backporting.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2012-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3